# Add checkBox at header of column in GWT(GXT)

Tags: javascript, gwt, checkbox, listener, gxt

I am looking for some way to add a checkBox at heaher of checkColumnConfig.
Below is the checkColumnConfig:

```
CheckColumnConfig checkColumn = new CheckColumnConfig("isReport",
    "Report", 25);
checkColumn.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
checkColumn.setRenderer(new GridCellRenderer<GuiReportNode>() {
    @Override
    public CheckBox render(final GuiReportNode model, String property, ColumnData config,
        int rowIndex, int colIndex, ListStore<GuiReportNode> store,
        Grid<GuiReportNode> grid) {

    final String name = model.get("name");
    final CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox();
    if (name.equals("System")) {
        checkBox.setValue(true);
        checkBox.disable();
    } else {
        final boolean isReport = model.get("isReport");
        if (isReport) {
        checkBox.setValue(true);
        }

        checkBox.addListener(Events.OnChange, new Listener<BaseEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(BaseEvent be) {
            for(CheckBox tmp : historicalCheckBoxList)
            {
                if(tmp.getData("name").equals(name))
                {
                    if(checkBox.getValue()) tmp.enable();
                    else tmp.disable();
                    break;
                }
            }
            editGridStore.findModel(model).setIsReport(checkBox.getValue());
        }
        });
    }
    checkBox.setData("name", name);
    reportCheckBoxList.add(checkBox);
    return checkBox;
    }
});
```

And I have tried to add a checkBox by using setWidget() method as below

```
final CheckBox tmpBox = new CheckBox();
tmpBox.setValue(true);
tmpBox.setBoxLabel("Report");
tmpBox.addListener(Events.OnChange, new Listener<BaseEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handleEvent(BaseEvent be) {
        logger("Click " + tmpBox.getValue().toString());
    }
});
LayoutContainer lc = new LayoutContainer();
lc.setLayout(new FitLayout());
lc.add(tmpBox);
checkColumn.setSortable(false);
checkColumn.setWidget(lc, "Report");
```

However, the checkBox will not work correctly, such as not check/uncheck while clicking it, and/or always get true value on its Event.OnChange.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: are you using gxt 2? what version do you use?

Comment: Hi wizard, sorry for the late reply, I am using gxt 2.2.5 currently. Thanks